# Angularjs - Best practices for controllers / routing / partials

Tags: angularjs, web-deployment

So I am just starting out with angularjs and web development in general and had a few questions regarding the best practices. Some of my questions are actually more related to web development in general.

1) When to use partials and when to use a different page instead. E.g Is is good to embed about.html as a partial in index.html or have a separate page?

2) What is the best way to share data between controllers? Right now I am using query parameters in the route.

3) Should I be using one controller for multiple partials?

Thanks!

Comment: Something I'd highly recommend checking out is the Angular seed project. The seed project provides a base skeleton for a typical Angular app: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed This baseline helped tremendously when I was first learning Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Angular is a single page app framework, so you only want to use one html 'page' in most cases. There may be exceptions but unless your project is very large you won't need to use more than one.
2. **Services** are the recommended way of doing this. Services return a singleton object, and you can inject references to them using angular's dependency injection. It keeps everything modular, too. Query params are definitely **not** what you want to use. For calling events between controllers you might also use `$scope.$broadcast()`.
3. Potentially, you might have an overall `AppController` for example that encompasses elements that have their own controllers (in their own directives, or using `ng-controller`). On the subject of directives, remember to use them to bundle re-usable components up. Directives have their own templates and controllers, and using them makes your code much more modular and easier to maintain/test.